# Choose biggest value from excel columns and check if condition is matched

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got couple columns that contains number from 1 to 5. After these columns there's column that have some letter. For example:

```
1 2 3 c
2 2 4 d
4 4 5 d
```

I need to check if column with letters represent proper letter. It depends on biggest number in first 3 columns.

For example if biggest number in a row is 5, than letter should be 'E' as it's 5th in alphabet. Otherwise I need to change color of the letter.

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: So in the example 3rd row is wrong, there should be E, not D at the end

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting with a formula like:

```
=MAX($A1:$C1)+64<>CODE(UPPER($D1))
```

Applied to Column D

[image]

Comment: Thank you kind Sir for fast reply!